# Where to put files that will be read in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conventions

I'm developing a Rails application and within that application I developed a Rake task that will read entries from a file and store them into the DB. Producing the code was no problem, but I'd like to know, where do I place the file that is read? Is there a convention for that, if yes, what is it?

I know I could have used the seed.rb file but is it ok, by the standards, to load and read a file from there?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, put the data you wish to load in the *db/seeds.rb* file and to load it run `rake db:seed`. This is what this file was designed to do.

Comment: +1 I didn't even know about this task. The problem is that there's no migration/versioning for seed, is there?

Comment: Do you mean reading the file from seeds.rb? If that's what you meant, what to do when there are many files to be read?

Comment: @Guilhereme Any ruby code can be in seeds.rb, so it can refer to other files. Make a directory under db called seed, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a hard and fast Rails convention for this case. When it comes to seed data I put mine in a subfolder of `db`.

Answer (score 0):

Where to put stuff in Rails is a problem that [I've been working around for a while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068558/oo-design-in-rails-where-to-put-stuff). The question is whether your file can fit into one of the existing concerns. For instance, is it configuration information?

Anyway, perhaps a similar fit would be the schema.rb, which is put in the `db` directory. **Do not modify the schema.rb with your data, of course:** I'm merely suggesting that the db directory, or a subdirectory, might be a place to put your file(s).

On the other hand, if you don't see any directories that hold anything similar -- it's not one of the main categories in `app`, nor any of the main categories above that -- then you can just make up a name and use that.

Comment: Never, EVER edit db/schema.rb! It will be updated every time you run a migration.

Comment: When you delete comments these conversations become surreal.

Answer (score 0):

The yaml_db plugin dumps/loads content from/to the database from the file 
rails_root/db/data.yml i'm not sure if this is by convention, however, the content is db related making the db folder an appropriate choice