# Rails 3.2.x: how to reload app/classes dir during development?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some Rails code that does not fit neatly into a model or controller box. So as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1071510/93995), I created a `app/classes` directory. Rails 3 seems to automatically add this to the "load path" in Rails, and my application correctly finds the classes I define in there without needing to use `require` statements.

However the code in `app/classes` does not get reloaded in development mode; if I make a change, I need to restart the server in order to see that change.

What's the proper way to make a given directory "reloadable" in Rails 3.2.x? A few answers here recommend doing:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/classes)
```

but I believe that this merely has the effect of adding `app/classes` to the initial set of directories to find code in; does not seem to make them reloadable for each request (and furthermore in 3.x it seems that `app/*` is automatically added).

**Update**:

Figures, I stumbled upon the solution a mere 30 seconds after posting the question:

I had my class wrapped inside a module. Once I removed the surrounding "MyModule", it suddenly became reloadable. Coming from a Java background, and having been burnt by Ruby code that pollutes the global namespace, I've developed a habit of putting everything inside a module. I guess Rails "app" code must live outside of any module?

Comment: Try to create a sub-directory under `classes` with the name of you module, then putting all the module's classes in there. I suspect if a file named `bar.rb` is changed, it is only reloaded if the class `Bar` is used, but not if the full name is actually `Foo::Bar` - then it would look for a file named `foo/bar.rb` to reload. Just a guess, though.

Answer (score 2):

Did you declare the module in a separate file, or did you declare it implicitly inside the class? This might have an effect on autoload behavior. `module Foo; class Bar` vs. `class Foo::Bar`. It might be if the Rails autoloader can't find a `foo.rb` to go with the Foo module it might skip reloading it.

Comment: Module was declared in same file like: Module Foo; class Bar, and then referred to throughout the code as Foo::Bar.

Comment: It might be worth trying to have a separate module file just so there's a 1:1 association between classes/modules and files.