# Where to put a class that is used by helpers and controllers but is not a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a class `Semester` that will be used to query a database using `ActiveRecord` to get the current semester, previous semester, and next semester by date. However, I won't have a controller or route for this, so I can't put it into the `app/models/` directory, but where should I put it? A `concerns` directory, or the `lib` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A model doesn't necessarily need to be part of a full resource, with route and controller : if it maps some kind of data entity, it's a model - especially if it's a subclass of active_record.

So `app/models/` is the perfect place for your `Semester` model.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068558/oo-design-in-rails-where-to-put-stuff

Comment: @PeterAlfvin : always useful, but not sure it applies here : the problem was not that much having load of logic in models, but more the misinterpretation that any model should be part of a resource with routes and dedicated controller.

Comment: I agree that your answer was sufficient to address his specific question (and I just upvoted it), but because he had this question/misunderstanding, I though the other question (and the 175-upvoted answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1071510/1008891) in particular, might be useful. That's why I said "see also".