# How to make a "pivot table" on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First, I'd like to mention I'm COMPLETELY new to Ruby and Rails, I'm on my very first days of learning, so I apologize if I seem a bit unclear or too broad with my questions.

I'm trying to do something simple (I think?), which is to pivot a table.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
----------------------------------
| Name     | Product ID | Amount |
|----------|----------------------
| Robert   |     P1     |   2    |
| Michael  |     P2     |   1    |
| Leonard  |     P2     |   1    |
| Robert   |     P2     |   4    |
| Robert   |     P3     |   2    |
| Michael  |     P3     |   1    |
----------------------------------
```

... and I'd like to to turn it into something like this:

```
---------------------------
| Name     | P1 | P2 | P3 |
---------------------------
| Robert   | 2  | 4  | 2  |
| Michael  | -  | 1  | 1  |
| Leonard  | -  | 1  | -  |
---------------------------
```

I'm not too sure how to achieve that. I've looked around and haven't found anything specific to my question.

I found a gem called pivot_table, which can be found here: https://github.com/edjames/pivot_table but I have no clue how to *exactly* use it. It has a small guide in it, but I don't know where to place the code.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: First you need to decide where you want to use this table. Do you want just display this table on the same page or you want to make some further transformations?

Comment: Does this information come from a database? You could do it in SQL instead of implementing in Ruby, which is likely to be quicker

Comment: @bronislav I want to display it on a page. The page would be dynamic, though that's a bit irrelevant. No changes would be made to the original tables though, it's just for cross-referencing data. Mind you, I oversimplified the tables, there'd be more data coming from the Products table, for instance.

Comment: @acutesoftware Yup, comes from a database, and I'm aware of the SQL method. I've considered it, but I was wondering if there'd be an easier way I could work out within Rails itself.

Comment: @user3209270, put pivot table generation in the relevant controller action and then use produced table in the view. If you don't know what controller or view is, than first read about [controllers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) and [views](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at your table and the results you're looking for, I would do it like this ( I assume it's an orders table ?)

```
result = []
Order.all.group_by(&:name).each do |name, orders|
  record = {}
  record["name"] = name
  orders.each do |order|
    record[order.product_id] = order.amount
  end
  result.append(record)
end
```

I hope this will give you a good starting point !

Comment: It is an orders table, yes. I tried your code (I think I understood the general idea you tried to suggest), but I'm getting an error about the number of arguments in the 2nd line (1 of 0). I do have an @orders variable that contains the table (@orders = Order.all), could this be the cause?

Comment: Sorry, there was a missing & before :name.
Another way to implement it would be group_by{ |order| order.name}.each ... both are equivalent.

@orders should have Order.all in it so it should be all good by now.

Answer (score 5):

First install the gem

```
# In your Gemfile
gem 'pivot_table'
```

Then in your terminal, run

```
bundle install
```

Say the model represented by your first table is `Sale`.

```
sales = Sale.all
grid = PivotTable::Grid.new do |g|
  g.source_data  = sales
  g.column_name  = :product_id
  g.row_name     = :name
end
```

Then you can use the other methods listed in the docs.  For example

```
g.column_headers # ['P1', 'P2', 'P3']
```

Note:  this is just from reading the GitHub page you linked.  I've never used the gem.

Edit:

You can put the code in a module:

```
# lib/PivotTable
module PivotTable
  def grid(data, options = {})
    grid = PivotTable::Grid.new do |g|
      g.source_data = data
      g.column_name = options[:column_name]
      g.row_name = options[:row_name]
    end
  end
end
```

Then you'd call it from somewhere else with

```
include PivotTable

def my_method
  sales = Sale.all
  grid = grid(sales, { :row_name => :name, :column_name => :product_id })
  # do stuff
end
```

This way you can reuse the grid-generating code and call it with arbitrary parameters.

Comment: Yeah, I got that far. Where would you place that code though? In the controller?

Comment: You could put it in a module.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm still not used to the rails jargon. Where would that be?

Comment: Not sure if you're asking about modules or where to put them or both so, modules: http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/modules.html

Comment: And where to put them in the Rails director structure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068558/oo-design-in-rails-where-to-put-stuff

Comment: Thanks! I'll check those out.

Comment: Note: This gem is does not aggregate data like a pivot table. It only maps objects into a matrix without aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general solution, that I implemented in `application_helper.rb`

```
def pivot_table row_model, column_model, pivot_model, pivot_attribute
  row_model.all.map do |r|
    column_model.select(:id).sort.map do |c|
      pivot_model.find_by(
        row_model.to_s.downcase => r,
        column_model.to_s.downcase => c
      )&.public_send(pivot_attribute) || 0
    end
  end
end
```

The first three parameters are capital-letter `ActiveRecord` subclass names, and the `pivot_attribute` (which is an attribute of `pivot_model`) can be given as a symbol or a string. This assumes `pivot_model` is a many-to-many relation that references `row_model` and `column_model` as foreign keys. If there isn't a many-many model, I'm guessing some models could be repeated among the parameters, but I haven't kitchen tested it for that.

The return value is an array of arrays.