# How to query LOGIN time and LOGOU time from attendance logs?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have an attendance table

```
employee_id | date | time | IN_OUT

1234 | 02-27-2017 | 12:00:01 | IN

1234 | 02-27-2017 | 12:02:01 | IN

1234 | 02-27-2017 | 09:00:05 | OUT
```

I want to retrieve the in and out by date like this

```
employee_id | date | IN | OUT

1234 | 02-27-2017 | 12:00:01 |  09:00:05

1234 | 02-28-2017 | 12:30:01 |  10:00:05
```

is it possible to retrive it using one query ?

Comment: yes, it's possible

Comment: any pointers or sample?

Comment: take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202371/how-to-make-a-pivot-table-on-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: so I will manipulate it in application side and not in sql?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.employee_id, a.date, b.time as in_time, c.time as out_time
FROM login a 
INNER JOIN login b on a.userId = b.userId AND b.action="in" 
LEFT JOIN login c on a.userId = c.userId AND c.action!="in"
```