# Cannot access models from /lib in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I make a script to try some functions. But I cannot use models in lib. Interesting is, that I already have an lib, and there it works fine with the mostly same code(?).

```
// script/tags.rb:
require File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require 'company_tags'

host = ARGV[0] || 'team1.crm.tld'

c = CompanyTags.new(host)
c.run

// lib/company_tags.rb
class CompanyTags 
  def initialize(host)
    @site = Site.where(host: host).first
  end

  def run
    comp = @site.companies.first
    comp.tag_list.add("tag1")
    comp.general_list.add("tag_general")
    comp.save!
    p comp.tag_list
  end
end
```

Error: /lib/company_tags.rb:3:in `initialize': uninitialized constant CompanyTags::Site (NameError)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to require the environment, not the application.

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment',  __FILE__)
require 'company_tags'
```

The environment will load all the dependencies, including the application, and it will bootstrap the application.

Comment: Wow. Thank you, it works very well. But, you can explain me, why the same code work for another pairs of script+lib? There i used application.

Comment: It may have worked because it was loaded in a different way, for example via console. Or because you are not using models defined in the environment.

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea, but try changing `Site.where(host: host).first` to `::Site.where(host: host).first`.  Putting the `::` in front, causes ruby to look for `Site` in the global namespace instead of as a constant defined in `CompanyTags`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, error differs few: in `initialize': uninitialized constant Site (NameError)

Comment: OK, cool - that at least rules out it being a constant lookup issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a simple configuration to `config/application.rb`:

```
# Autoload lib/ folder including all subdirectories
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068558/oo-design-in-rails-where-to-put-stuff) out for more details.

Comment: I think you isn't are right, couse I running it from console.

Comment: actually `rails console` or `rails c` commands load all your application files including the gems.

Comment: Huh. I mean terminal. I just run a script, like this: ruby script/tags.rb. 

But anyway, i'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

In my previous answer, I thought you were running rails console. Your main issue is that the Site class is not required. Here is how requiring files to your classes work.

Through the `require_all` function

> require_all(MY_CLASSES_DIRECTORY)

Or by requiring each class manually:

> require 'Class_NAME.rb'

Notice that the `Site` class is not required anywhere.

For more details, check this [link](http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/loading)