# Rails undefined method for Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails, how do you use a specific method from a module. For eg,

```
# ./app/controllers/my_controller.rb
class MyController < ApplicationController
  include MyModule 

  def action
    MyModule.a_method
  end

  private
  def a_method
    ...
  end
end

# ------------------------------------------------ #

# ./app/helpers/my_module.rb
module MyModule 
  def a_method
    ...
  end
end
```

`MyController` includes MyModule. And in `action` ,I want to use `MyModule.a_method` (Please note I also have a private `a_method` in MyController and I *don't* want to use this.)

Things I've tried :

1) Defining the method in the module as `self.`

```
def self.a_method
end
```

2) Using the `::` notation in controller (`MyModule::a_method`)

The error that I keep getting is 
`Undefined method:a_method for MyModule:module`
For now, I've resorted to using a different name for the modules method. But I'd like to know how to namespace the function with either the `Module::` or `Module.` notation

**[UPDATE - 11/24/2014]**
adding file structure in code, since Rails heavily relies on convention.

Comment: guessing that my_module.rb is saved in your lib/ directory?  did you try requiring your module in an initializer or in application.rb?

Comment: Updated the code section with the paths of my files.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So I am not really sure what you are trying to accomplish with your module but a quick solution to get it working is below.

1. Move my_module.rb out of helpers and into lib/my_module.rb.  The helpers directory is for methods that you use in your views.  The convention is to utilize helpers that are namespaced after their respective controller or the application_helper.rb for global methods for your views.  Not sure if that's what you are trying to accomplish with your module but wanted to throw that out there.
2. Create an initializer (you can all it whatever) in config/initializers/custom_modules.rb and add `require 'my_module'`
3. Update the a_method back to be `self.a_method`
4. You can now call `MyModule.a_method` in your app

Don't forget to restart your server for changes to lib/my_module.rb to take effect.

Also, a lot of people reference [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068558/oo-design-in-rails-where-to-put-stuff/1071510#1071510) by Yehuda Katz as guidance on where to store code for your app.  Thought it might be a helpful reference.

Comment: ended up putting the module in a lib dir and requoring it in an initializer.

Answer (score 7):

if you include MyModule into MyController, all the "instance methods" of the first will be mixed-in into the 2nd.

So if you only want to call MyModule.a_method, **no need** to include your module.

Then you'd want to require (or better autoload) your module before using it. To do so place it in controllers/concerns/my_module.rb, rails (4 at least) should autoload it, otherwise require its file in an intializer

```
# my_module.rb
module MyModule 
  def self.a_method
    ...
  end
end
```

should work, but doing

```
# my_module.rb
module MyModule 
  extend self
  def a_method
    ...
  end
end
```

is more clean to me. You'd like to have a look to rails [active support concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) to understand the "rails way" on this topic.