# How do you get the Rails 5 test runner to run tests in a non-standard tests/* folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have classes in my app that don't really fit the typical Rails file structure. Based on Yehuda Katz's advice in [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1071510/1927876), I decided to make an `app/classes` folder. I'd like to test these classes, so I also made a `test/classes` folder.

My problem is that I can't seem to get the test runner to run the tests in `test/classes` - how can I get it to do so?

I have `app/classes/card.rb` and `test/classes/card_spec.rb`. Here is what is currently happening:

```
code/poker_analyzer [master●] » test
code/poker_analyzer [master●] » test test/classes/card_spec.rb
code/poker_analyzer [master●] » bin/rails test
Running via Spring preloader in process 8991
Run options: --seed 14207

# Running:



Finished in 0.000522s, 0.0000 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
0 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
code/poker_analyzer [master●] » bin/rails test test/classes/card_spec.rb
Running via Spring preloader in process 9005
Run options: --seed 33782

# Running:

.

Finished in 0.001655s, 604.2296 runs/s, 604.2296 assertions/s.
1 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
code/poker_analyzer [master●] »
```

So it seems to only work when I run `bin/rails test test/classes/card_spec.rb`. How can I get it to run in the other scenarios?

Update: It is only supposed to work in the scenarios prefaced by `bin/rails`. So then, my question is why `bin/rails test` doesn't work.

Comment: Check out this blog http://blog.bigbinary.com/2014/04/26/adding-directory-to-rake-test.html

Comment: this could also be helpful https://medium.com/@mario_chavez/testing-rails-with-minitest-7b4f99d4fcb8

Comment: @George The first blog post is somewhat useful as a hack, but I'm looking for the approach that follows whatever Convention Over Configuration is currently available. I didn't see an answer in the second article, and it wasn't explicitly for Rails 5.

Comment: according to the  minitest docs, you should be using a rake task like `bin/rails test` to run your test suite https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest#running-your-tests

Comment: @George something seems off if `test` works for things in the default folders, but doesn't work for things in the non-default folders. I assume there is some Rails convention to make it work for non-default folders too. Otherwise, I agree that the best answer is to just run `bin/rails test`, which works when I changed the file names to `_test` like you pointed out.

Comment: does `test` work for the things in default folders? in the code snipped you posted it doesn't look like `test` is doing anything

Comment: @George No... it doesn't. My bad! I'm new to rails and was assuming for some reason that `test` is supposed to work, and that the reason it wasn't working is because my app doesn't currently have anything except `app/classes` stuff. My only question then is why `bin/rails test` wasn't working, but you answered that by saying that files need to have the `_test` suffix. I updated my OP to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147976/discussion-between-george-and-adam-zerner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only used RSpec so this is kind of speculation, but I'm pretty sure the suffix of your `test/classes/card_spec.rb` file has to be `_test` not `_spec` for it to be picked up automatically by the runner.

So change the name to`test/classes/card_test.rb` and it should work.

Comment: It works when I run `bin/rails test`, but not when I run `test`.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @Adam, I'm going to delete my answer -- I don't think it's correct. I couldn't find documentation anywhere.

Comment: Or I'm confused, did it work for you? because `test` without bin/rails in front of it is a bash command https://ss64.com/bash/test.html

Comment: I wouldn't say that it "worked". `test` is supposed to run all of your tests, and it isn't.

Comment: I don't think there is a `test` command that's supposed to run all of your tests. `test` without `bin/rails` or `rake`  in front of it is a system tool that I linked before (type `man test` in your command line and you'll see the manual for it). `bin/rails test` is supposed to "Runs all tests in test folder except system ones" and according to the docs http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#bin-rails it looks like using `bin/rails test` is now the standard.